# PHP - Get multiple email attachments

Tags: php, email, email-attachments

I was able to modify the code below in order to save the email attachment in a specific folder and get the link of attachment and download it.
Everything works so far however, if an email has more than one attachment the script outputs (echo) just the first attachment name and link, but it saves all of them in the server folder.

Example: (one attachment - works fine)

Attachment: attachment_1.jpg

Download Link: Download

---

Example: (more than one attachment)

Attachment: attachment_1.jpg, attachment_2.jpg, etc..

Download Link: Download 1, Download 2, etc..

---

How can I print all the attachments names of an email?

```
echo 'Attachment:' . ' ' . $name[0] . '</br>'; ???
```

See code below.

```
    $structure = imap_fetchstructure($imap, $m);

    $attachments = array();
    if (isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) {

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) {

            $attachments[$i] = array(
                'is_attachment' => false,
                'filename' => '',
                'name' => '',
                'attachment' => ''
            );

            if ($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) {
                foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) {
                    if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') {
                        $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                        $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) {
                foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) {
                    if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                        $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                        $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) {
                $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($imap, $m, $i+1);
                if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) { // 3 = BASE64
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                }
                elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) { // 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($attachments as $key => $attachment) {
        $name = $attachment['name'];
        $contents = $attachment['attachment'];
        file_put_contents(STYLESHEETPATH . '/email_attachments/' . $name, $contents);
    }

    $download_link = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/email_attachments/' . $name;

    //imap_setflag_full($imap, $i, "\\Seen");
    //imap_mail_move($imap, $i, 'Trash');
    //print_r($attachment);
    echo '</br>From:' . ' ' . $from_email . '</br>';
    echo 'To:' . ' ' . $to . '</br>';

    if($name){
        echo 'Attachment:' . ' ' . $name . '</br>';
        echo 'Path Saved: ' . ' ' . STYLESHEETPATH . '/email_attachments/' . $name . '</br>';
        echo 'Download Link: ' . ' ' . '<a href="' . $download_link . '"> Download</a>' . '</br>';
    }

    echo 'Subject:' . ' ' . $subject . '</br></br>';
}
```

Comment: You need to add a foreach to iterate trough all attachment names.

Comment: thats what I tough hover, not sure where to add it. I have tried on  echo 'Attachment:' . ' ' . $name . '</br>'; but not doing nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
if($name){
    echo 'Attachment:' . ' ' . $name . '</br>';
    echo 'Path Saved: ' . ' ' . STYLESHEETPATH . '/email_attachments/' .$name . '</br>';
    echo 'Download Link: ' . ' ' . '<a href="' . $download_link . '"> Download</a>' . '</br>';
}
```

You are printing just one attachment (the last that left from the foreach iteration), you need to wrap that in a foreach like

```
foreach ($attachments as $key => $attachment) {
    $name = $attachment['name'];
    $contents = $attachment['attachment'];
    // Put your code to print here.
}
```